# Controller Design using Webots!

Tags: control, first-robotics, webots

I am trying to work on a Digital Twin of a Physical Robot which is used at my uni. I made a rough model of the robot using Webots (Open source). I need to design certain controllers aiming at the Tilt, Heading, Velocity control of the robot. Can anyone explain to me the implementation & the initial steps for designing the control part using Webots?

Comment: Is the idea that the controllers are going to be developed in simulation and then ported to the physical robot, or is it the other way around — you want to enable control code originally written for the physical robot to run in simulation?

Comment: @xperroni Yeah you get it right. I have some raw control loop implementation of the robot in MATLAB, I want to implement something similar in webots. I am basically going to compare the simulation robot and the physical robot and see how well the loops replicate and how well the robot performs.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have controller code written for the physical robot, I recommend creating a set of adapters so you can run the same code in Webots, instead of rewriting everything from scratch.

The [Webots User Guide](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/) provides extensive guidance on how to setup and interface with the platform. In particular I recommend taking a look into the chapters on how to [setup MATLAB language support](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-matlab?tab-language=matlab) and the [Webots MATLAB API](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/matlab). You'll probably also want to go through the [tutorials](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorials), especially the one about [controllers](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-4-more-about-controllers?tab-language=matlab). Notice that MATLAB code snippets are provided, but you may have to click the corresponding button in the code window to visualize it:

[image]